# If/Else in Modx

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I'm trying to wrap in my template a block in conditionals:

```
<div class="widget widget_categories trip_widget">
    <div class="kd-widget-title"><h4>Book online</h4></div>
    <div class="trip-book-button">
        <a href="[(site_url)]book-online.html/#id=[*trip-slug*]">Book now online</a>        
    </div>
</div>
```

> I need to show that block only if `[*trip-slug*]` is present.

I've read through the forum and the documentation but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Evolution you need the PHx plugin (https://github.com/Temus/PHx) to process resource or template variable tags. With that plugin you could use the following code:

```
[*trip-slug:ne=`
  <div class="widget widget_categories trip_widget">
    <div class="kd-widget-title"><h4>Book online</h4></div>
    <div class="trip-book-button">
      <a href="[(site_url)]book-online.html/#id=[*trip-slug*]">Book now online</a>        
    </div>
  </div>
`*]
```

Placeholder tags inside Ditto are parsed with a (limited) PHx parser and you could use the following inside a Ditto template without the plugin:

```
[+trip-slug:ne=`
  <div class="widget widget_categories trip_widget">
    <div class="kd-widget-title"><h4>Book online</h4></div>
    <div class="trip-book-button">
      <a href="[(site_url)]book-online.html/#id=[+trip-slug+]">Book now online</a>        
    </div>
  </div>
`+]
```

In both cases you could also work with the Evolution core **if** Snippet.

```
[[if? &is=`[*trip-slug*]:not_empty` &then=`
  <div class="widget widget_categories trip_widget">
    <div class="kd-widget-title"><h4>Book online</h4></div>
    <div class="trip-book-button">
      <a href="[(site_url)]book-online.html/#id=[*trip-slug*]">Book now online</a>        
    </div>
  </div>
`]]
```

Replace the [* *] with [+ +] inside of Ditto template chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [Output Filter](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/input-and-output-filters-(output-modifiers)) in MODX Revolution (which is what this page is tagged with) or a [PHx filter](http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/PHx) in MODX Evolution (which is what the syntax of your placeholders suggests you're using).

**MODX Evolution**

```
[+trip-slug:ne=`
  <div class="widget widget_categories trip_widget">
    <div class="kd-widget-title"><h4>Book online</h4></div>
    <div class="trip-book-button">
      <a href="[(site_url)]book-online.html/#id=[*trip-slug*]">Book now online</a>        
      </div>
  </div>
`+]
```

**MODX Revolution**

```
[[*trip-slug:notempty=`
  <div class="widget widget_categories trip_widget">
    <div class="kd-widget-title"><h4>Book online</h4></div>
    <div class="trip-book-button">
      <a href="[(site_url)]book-online.html/#id=[*trip-slug*]">Book now online</a>        
    </div>
  </div>
`]]
```

Comment: The button is not show even if `[*trip-slug*]` is present.

Comment: I'm on Evolution btw.